# Doubt on proof of theorem 14.22 of Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

I don't understand what I've marked in yellow in the following theorem of Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis

[image]

I think I know why $\{f(z_n)\}$ has no limit point in $A_2$, because if there exists a subsequence $\{f(z_{n_k})\}$ convergent to some point $w \in A_2$, then as $f^{-1}$ is continuous, we have that
$$z_{n_k}=f^{-1}(f(z_{n_k})) \longrightarrow f^{-1}(w) \in A_1$$
but $|z_{n_k}|$ converges to $1$, so $|f^{-1}(w)|=1$ having a contradiction with $f^{-1}(w)$ being in $A_1$.

What I don't get is why $|f(z_n)|$ converges to $1$ and what does the assumption that $1< |z| < 1+ \varepsilon$ and the note that $f(z_n) \in V$ have to do with this convergence. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think what is confusing you is the line:

"In the latter case replace f by R_2/f"

You see only the former case is discussed, the latter case is left to the reader to use the same reasoning after a transformation. So everything that follows assumes the former case.

The former case doesn't let V anywhere near the outer boundary, that is what V subset of A(1,r) means. r is strictly smaller than that outer boundary.

f(z_n) has no limit points in A_2 implies that |f(z_n)| has no limit points in (1,R_2), but also |f(z_n)| is bounded within [1,r] and so must have a limit point by compactness. [1,r] take away (1,R_2) is the singleton {1}. |f(z_n)| is bounded in the real numbers has one and only one limit point which is 1 so it converges to 1. The proof of that may take a lemma if you haven't seen it before.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).